# Logical tests on Cell Arrays

Tags: matlab, cell-array

When dealing with regular arrays in Matlab it's very easy to perform logical tests and to set the cells that fail those tests to a desired value such as NaN without having to use for loops.

```
TestA=[1 2 10 45];
TestA(TestA<=2)=NaN;
```

I have a cell array where I can do the logical test OK, but how can I then turn the cell array elements that fail the test to NaN without using a for loop?

```
TestCell{1}=[1 2 10 45];
TA=TestCell{1} <= 2;
```

Thanks

Baz

Comment: What is the reason of avoiding the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same concept holds true for cell array elements if they are numeric arrays.

```
TestCell{1}(TestCell{1} <= 2) = NaN;
```

Now if you want to loop through *all* of the elements of the cell without an explicit for loop, this is a little difficult because you can't do assignment within `cellfun`.

The alternative is to construct some expression which will return an array where there are NaNs when your condition is true and the original values elsewhere.

Such an expression could look like this:

```
x .* ~(x <= 2) ./ ~(x <= 2);
```

This will cause each element to be multiplied by `0/0` (`NaN`) when the condition is true and multiplied by `1/1` (1) when the condition is false. In this way, all values that meet the condition will be set to NaNs.

If we try this on your example data:

```
x = [1 2 10 45];
x .* ~(x <= 2) ./ ~(x <= 2)

    NaN   NaN    10    45
```

We get the NaN's where your condition is true. So now we can plug this into `cellfun` to perform this operation on all contents.

```
output = cellfun(@(x)x .* ~(x <= 2)./~(x <= 2), TestCell, 'uni', 0);
```

The alternative is to write the conditional backwards so all elements which *don't* meet the criteria will be set to NaN. This will prevent having to negate both of the conditionals in the above equations.

```
x = [1 2 10 45]
x .* (x > 2) ./ (x > 2)
```

And we can plug this into `cellfun` like we did above.

```
output = cellfun(@(x)x .* (x > 2) ./ (x > 2), TestCell, 'uni', 0);
```

The primary disadvantage of this approach is that it requires you to evaluate the conditional *twice* as there is no good way to store the intermediate result within `cellfun`. This may or may not be an issue depending upon how big each element is. There really is no shame in having a for loop for doing this sort of thing as it is likely more performant than the solution here.

Comment: Isn't that a sort of hack against the self-defence of MATLAB? The cell array, unlike normal arrays, can contain elements with different types. When operating with elements of same type, there is no need to use cell arrays.

Comment: @Crowley Could be elements of the same type but different dimensions.

Comment: If you take vector or string as type You are right. But string is a array of `char` and vector is array of `double`.

Comment: @Crowley I'm referring to this scenario. `C = {[1,2,3], [1,2]}`

Comment: Which is array of arrays not array of doubles. `{A,B}` will create new array with two elements `A` and `B` but `[A,B]` will concatenate arrays `A` and `B` regardless what `A` and `B` are. In your example the '3' is accessible as C{1}(3) not as C{1,3}.

Comment: @Crowley I'm a little confused what you're trying to point out here. Technically [*all* variables are arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-numeric-arrays.html), even a scalar double. Regardless, the example I posted above is a perfectly valid reason to use a cell array to store multi-element arrays of doubles.

Comment: I tried to point that `C=[[1,2,3],[10,20]]` will concatenate double arrays in double array C, thus `10` can be called by `C(1,5)`. On the other hand `C={[1,2,3],[10,20]} will encapsulate two double arrays in cell array `C`, thus `10` can be called by `C{1,2}(1,2)`. If you want to merge arrays `[]` is the command. But if you want to put arrays side-by-side `{}` is the command.

Comment: My original point refered to scenario `TestCell={1,2,'a',gcf,[1,2;3,4]}`